# Trouble with Airtable API and Python

Tags: python, module, importerror, attributeerror, airtable

I am using an online spreadsheet app called AirTable and need to be able to access the API using Python.

There is a python interface to the API as outlined on Github:
https://github.com/bayesimpact/airtable-python

I've followed the getting started directions and when I run the code I get the following error:
AttributeError: module 'airtable' has no attribute 'Airtable'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temporary fix:

```
from airtable import airtable
```

Permanent fix:

1 find your airtable installed path

2 find the **ini** file

3 Remove the #

4 Specify the class you need to use once imported

```
from airtable import airtable

class Airtable(object):
    pass
```

May be more class you need to add.

Comment: tried your temp fix and got this:

ImportError: cannot import name 'airtable'

Comment: @daveaseeman make sure you clone the airtable git repository into your application. It should work then.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. The filename which I was writing in was named `airtable.py`
When I changed the filename to `air.py` it was able to import airtable without an issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, check that if your project has a file name "airtable.py"

"You should never use the same name for a python file that is for a python library, python confuses its self, deciding where should it import, its priority is to import from the project files first and go to libraries later"

if that does not works then you may have installed the wrong library

```
pip uninstall airtable
```

python working library for airtbale is

```
pip install airtable-python-wrapper
```